# Dealing damage with a net and the Quick Toss maneuver

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, battle-master

The net is a ranged thrown weapon that restrains an enemy that's struck by it, but deals no damage. To avoid the limitation that you don't get extra attacks when throwing a net with an attack action, one option is to use the Battlemaster maneuver "Quick Toss" from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*. Quick Toss allows you to draw and throw a single thrown weapon as a bonus action, adding your superiority die to the damage (and thus leaving your action free to make normal weapon attacks against the restrained target).

Quick Toss says:

> If you hit, add the superiority die to the weapon's damage roll.

The net's listed damage is "—". Would I treat that as a roll of zero, roll my superiority die, and deal just the single die of damage; or does "—" mean no damage roll happens and consequently there's nothing to add damage to?

Comment: As a side note, your premise is flawed. The description for net states, _"When you use an action, **bonus action**, or reaction **to attack with a net**, you can make **only one attack regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make**."_ Even though you switched the attack to a bonus attack, you still cannot use your Action to make any further attacks this turn.

Comment: I disagree, that's not what it says.  There isn't a "number of attacks you can normally make" in a turn. That's referring to anything that would let you make multiple attacks as part of a single attack action or whatnot.  When I attack with a net with a bonus action, and then use an Attack action later, that attack action isn't happening "when you use an action to attack with a net"